# How to handle potentially missing configuration file with serde

Tags: rust, serde

I am working on a configuration file which may or may not be present on the host system. So far I have a struct that looks like this:

```rust
struct Config {

    #[serde(default = "default_option_a")]
    option_a: String,

    #[serde(default = "default_option_b")]
    option_b: u8
}

fn default_option_a() -> String {
    return String::from("foo");
}

fn default_option_b() -> u8 {
    return 42;
}
```

In this case I am trying to parse from a toml file. The defaults work great when the toml file is present and missing some struct members, but I am curious how I should best handle the toml file being non-existant to begin with:

```rust
let config: Config = match std::fs::read_to_string("afile.conf") {
    Ok(config_content) => toml::from_str(&config_content).unwrap(),
    Err(err) => {
        println!("afile.conf file unreadable: {}", err);
        return toml::from_str("").unwrap();
    }
};
```

The error handler above fails with

```
panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error { inner: ErrorInner { kind: Custom, line: None, col: 0, message: "invalid type: map, expected unit", key: [] } }
```

Is there an idiomatic way to handle this using the serde defaults?

Comment: What first jumps to my mind is implementing `Default` for `Config` and using that default in the `Err` case - is there a reason that wouldn't work?

Comment: Nice idea - I think my hang up with that is getting it to work natively with the serde default macros already in place on the struct members - wouldn’t I have to duplicate that logic in the Default trait?

Comment: @WillAyd You could probably do something cheeky like `toml::Value::try_from(HashMap::new()).unwrap().try_into::<Config>().unwrap()`

Comment: You're panicking because you are using `unwrap` after the `from_str` method call. I would suggest you to make another match for `toml::from_str`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, this is a really weird problem. You're calling `return` when you shouldn't, which makes `from_str` infer the type you want to deserialize to the return type of the function this is in. When in `fn main() {` this is `()` (the unit type). That gives this error (formatted by me):

```rs
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value:
Error {
  inner: Error {
    inner: TomlError { 
      message: "invalid type: map, expected unit",
      original: Some(""), 
      keys: [], 
      span: Some(0..0)
    }
  }
}'
```

I believe this is because TOML always has a map as the top-level value. It looks like the toml crate doesn't have any TOML representation for `()`.

You don't want to return.

```rs
let config: Config = match std::fs::read_to_string("afile.conf") {
    Ok(config_content) => toml::from_str(&config_content).unwrap(),
    Err(err) => {
        println!("afile.conf file unreadable: {}", err);
        toml::from_str("").unwrap()
    }
};
```

This correctly gives you the defaults you have set:

```rs
Config {
    option_a: "foo",
    option_b: 42,
}
```

It would be more efficient to just implement `Default`, though.

```rs
impl Default for Config {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            option_a: default_option_a(),
            option_b: default_option_b(),
        }
    }
}
```

```rs
Err(err) => {
    println!("afile.conf file unreadable: {}", err);
    Config::default()
}
```

Comment: Ah this is great. Ironically I added return because originally I included the semicolon after the `unwrap()` call and that yielded `expected Config, found ()`; simple mistake with serious consequences

Comment: The problem with the `impl Default for Config` AFAICT is that if my configuration file is found but missing option_b I then get an error for `missing field option_b`. Accepting the answer in any case because the removal of return helped solve the issue, but not sure the alternative solution is apples-to-apples. In any case THANK YOU for the help

Comment: @WillAyd Yeah, you'd need `Default` in addition to the `serde(default)` attributes.